# aws amplify transferring app to a new owner after I sell it (hopefully)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am excited about the AWS Amplify framework, but I have a question I need an answer to.  If I make an app that does well and I want to sell it, am I able to transfer the app to a new owner?  I can always make a new root user, but I would strongly prefer not too.  Thanks!

Comment: One strategy would be to put everything related to a particular app in one AWS Account. That way, you can transfer ownership of the account, which would include everything it contains. This is much easier than trying to "recreate" an app later in a new AWS account (eg Transfer domain names, databases, permissions, etc).